# Layout Contents wont fit to screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I designed an app and wen i tested it out , the contents went outside the screen .can Someone Please Help me? how can i fix it?[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYfqa.png)
this is the xml. All the id's given Are matching to the text on the button.
Thanks in advance!:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logic"
            android:id="@+id/logic"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/easy"
            android:id="@+id/easy"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="127dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/hard"
            android:id="@+id/hard"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/math"
            android:id="@+id/math"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/whatami"
            android:id="@+id/whatami"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/kids"
            android:id="@+id/kids"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/funny"
            android:id="@+id/funny"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/riddu"
            android:id="@+id/riddlerrubix"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />


    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ImageViews `android:layout_width` `from 190dp` to `match_parent`.

Comment: Sorry , That din't work. If i do that , One button will cover the whole screen!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me please try it:

You need to add the dependency to your gradle file:

> com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.0.0

In addition just make sure in my answer, your `ImageView` height for each of the elements.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/easy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/easy" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hard"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="127dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/hard" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/whatami"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/whatami" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/kids"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/kids" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/funny"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/funny" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/riddlerrubix"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/riddlerrubix" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/math"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/math" />

    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```